# Given is a probability space. Prove that if $A \subseteq B$, then $B \setminus A \in \epsilon$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Given is a probability space $(\Omega, \epsilon, P)$ and the events
>   $A,B$
>
> Prove that if $A \subseteq B$, then $B \setminus A \in \epsilon$

I got that question from an exam of a *true or false* task but sadly there was no solution and I have no idea how this could be solved correctly?

Comment: Here $\epsilon$ is your $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @Mark yes they define in task like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: In this, I'm assuming that $A,B$ are in your $\sigma$-Algebra.
Additionally, we need that $A\subseteq B$ for $B\setminus A$ to be well-defined (it's possible we could define it as $B\setminus A = \emptyset$ when $A\supset B$, but I can't remember at the moment).

We have that $A,B\in\epsilon$, a $\sigma$-Algebra.  $\sigma$-Algebras are closed under both complements and countable unions.

We have that:

$$B\setminus A = B\cap A^c = (B^c\cup A)^c$$
I've rewritten this using an identity between absolute and relative complements (the first equality), and De Morgan's law (the second equality).

Now, it's in a form where it's clear that $B\setminus A$ is made from only $A,B$, countable unions, and complements, so must be in the $\sigma$-Algebra.